# Can I apply for immigration if I have a house mortgage to pay?

Tags: mortgage, banking, australia, china

I am planning to continue to pay the mortgage after immigration. But I don't know if the bank will allow me to pay house mortgage from another country.

Comment: Which country are you referring to- United States?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to talk to your mortgage lender about that, I doubt there is a 'generic' answer to it. I do currently have a house in another country that I'm paying a mortgage on, but the lender wasn't too happy with that. They still did accept it, but the bigger problem for me is refinancing it as an investment property when you're not in the country.

Also, it probably depends on what your plans are - are you planning to go abroad for a few years, then return? Emigrate for good? Rent out the place while you're gone?

As I can attest to, even with a local agent a house 5000 miles away can be more of a pain in the posterior than you'd expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to apply Australia Skilled Immigration(may be applying work visa at first). I owe mortgage here in China for a house which i am going to leave to my parents or rent it out. I don't know if the bank that issued me mortgage will try to prevent me from leaving as a suspect of default. However I will consult the bank.

Comment: The bank doesn't care too much if you leave the country. If you don't pay the mortgage, they can force the house to be sold and the mortgage will be paid back from the sales price. It doesn't really matter if you are in the country or not.

Comment: gnasher729, that depends very much on the country and your mortgage contract. In my case, I ended up having to sell my house in the UK and that was in no small part due to the way mortgage contracts are structured over there.